# typo3 add image resource as background

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typoscript2

I'm totally new to typo3, I need to make a div with background from a specific page. For example on home page, I would like to use a media resource from page id 20.

I got something like that

```
page.20 = TEMPLATE
page.20.template = FILE
page.20.template.file = fileadmin/refood/layouts/home.html
page.20.workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT
page.20.subparts{
  BOX1 < styles.content.get
  BOX1.select.where = colPos=1
  BOX1.wrap = <div class="offers"><div class="home-box-desc"></div><div class="home-box-desc">|</div><div class="meta-square-green"></div></div>
  BOX1.stdWrap.typolink.parameter = 14 _self home-box }
```

I tried to use something like that

```
  references {
     table = pages
     uid.data = 20
     fieldName = media
    }
     renderObj = IMAGE
     renderObj {
      file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
      altText.data = file:current:title
      wrap = <div class="offers">|</div>
    }
    BOX1.wrap = <div class="home-box-desc" style="background:url(|)"></div>
```

Into a subpart part, but nothing happens. How should I make it ?

Comment: What Version of TYPO3 are you using? Is there a reason you are not using fluid? What do you mean by "nothing happens"? What is the generated HTML?

Comment: 6.2.18 - the reason is, this site is done in this way, I have no time to remake It. By "nothing happens" I mean, there is no output on frontend, I can't see the style attribute. .

Comment: When you're using a 'hardcoded' value for the uid, you don't need the .data
Try settind uid = 20 without .data and see if that works out for you